# Weird network devices

Tags: c#, .net, networking, device

I am using NetworkInformation namespace to list all the network devices.

```
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

When I get the list, there are some weird unknown devices:

[image]

What are they? And should I, and if, then how, get rid of them? In theory it should show only Local Area Connection and Wireless Connection. Under Network Connections I can't find anything like that installed either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has network 'devices' that don't exist in terms of physical hardware - they're used for various things, such as VPN connections (like that tunneling pseudo interface) and the loopback adapter, which is what responds to 127.0.0.1

You can parse the non-physical addresses by using WMI to query the list of adapters instead,

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("Win32_NetworkAdapter")))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
    {
        if ((bool)mo["PhysicalAdapter"])
            Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"]);
    }
}
```

(taken from MSDN)

That'll only return physical devices, as you're casting the true/false value of the PhysicalAdapter property as bool.

Comment: Thank you, but what namespace I have to use it to get it work? System.Management; does not seem to work.

Comment: You need to add System.Management as a reference in the project also, along with 'using System.Management'

Answer (score 0):

I believe items such as "Local Area Connection* [number]" are due to VMs (are you running Virtual PC or something similar?).

The loopback adapter is there so you can ping your own IP address without being plugged into a network (i.e. to the adapter and back without using localhost or going to a router/switch and back over the network).

Not sure about the others, I'm afraid.

Comment: Toredo and isatap support transition ipv6 services i.e. ipv6 over ipv4.